# Building Apache HTTP Server with my own pthread library

Tags: apache, build, pthreads, installation, shared-libraries

I have my own version of pthread library, call it mypthread. I want to install Apache HTTP Server on my PC (Ubuntu 12.04). I am following http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html for the building process.

The problem is that I want to use my own version of pthread library. So, I would have to first build apr and apr-util libraries by linking mypthread instead of pthread and then build apache using mypthread.

I have thought of replacing every occurrence of "-lpthread" with "-L/path -lmypthread"? However, there are a lot of occurrences of-lpthreads and it would take a lot of time. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just rename your lib to libpthread.so.x.y.z?

Comment: @alk I found out that libpthread is located at 5 different locations on my system. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
/usr/lib32/libpthread.so /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /lib32/libpthread.so.0  Which one should be renamed? Also, by renaming, all the programs that use pthreads e.g. the terminal itself would start using myown pthreads library. So, there is a risk that the system would crash if there is a bug in my code.